# Swift: View not updating to programmatically set height constraint

Tags: swift, view, nslayoutconstraint

I have a calendarView from the CVCalendar pod (https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar/) and an issue with the custom View is it erratically sets the height of the view after rotation. To try and resolve this I have set a height constraint for it and am trying to set the height after the rotation to properly fit the view:

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
      print("Before height: \(calendarViewTestHeight.constant)")
      calendarViewTestHeight.constant = 500
      self.calendarView.layoutIfNeeded()
      print("After height: \(calendarViewTestHeight.constant)")
 }
```

When this code is called the height within the print statement changes as expected but the views height does not update.

Comment: Do you have any other constraints set? Do you see any auto layout error log printed in the debugger?

Comment: No the things printed are: Before height: 656.0 After height: 500.0

Comment: Try calling layoutifneeded() for the parent view where the calendarView is added. It might solve the problem.

Comment: calling self.view.layoutIfNeeded() instead produces the same results